# blocking an specific descriptor within epoll in c

Tags: c, sockets, epoll

Hi I need to have an specific file descriptor within the descriptors I am monitoring in epoll to block one descriptor is for a socket which is constantly getting broadcast messages but the user have to type an action in the keyboard that is my other descriptor this is the one I need to block because I start typing and then another broadcast message arrive and messes up with what I am writing.

Is there a way to pause an event for a file descriptor to detecting data ready or to block another file descriptor when it has the data ready?

Comment: That's almost guaranteed to be a completely wrong way of approaching this problem.

Comment: If you want to pause epoll events on a file descriptor you simply have to remove the descriptor from the epoll set. (or if you want only EPOLLOUT events, modify the descritor and remove the EPOLLIN flag)

Comment: I am kind of lost here I dont want to loose what i am receiving on the socket and I need to give time to the user to type in the next action to take what should I do take the stdin file descriptor out of epoll ?

Comment: As a bit of an aside, there's this new-fangled thingy called "punctuation". It makes the English language a little bit easier to read. Extremely long run-on sentences hurt peoples brains...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of ways to go.

1. If you are using `EPOLLET` (edge-triggered), then your event handler on wake-up can first check if you are in the middle of handling typed input from the console. If so, it can just not read anything, but set a flag. When the typed input handler is done, it checks that flag, and manually wakes up the socket input handler to handle the data.
2. If you are using level-triggered instead, then you can suppress th event by modifying the event set for that file descriptor to suppress the events you want to ignore. This can either be by using `EPOLL_CTL_MOD` with a new set of events, or by using `EPOLL_CTL_DEL` to unregister the file descriptor from `epoll` altogether. You would add back what was suppressed after you are finished with the typed input handler.

Comment: See this I like the most I am using edge triggered so in the part that I handle the user input set a flag to 1 for example and then for the other descriptor check for that flag and dont even enter the processing for that descriptor right?

Comment: Thanks @jxh I cannot test it right now but I will definitely let you know how it worked